# SQL Server dynamic query -- cannot locate linked server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, dynamicquery

```
declare @node int = 9044;

DECLARE @sqlCommand NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
(
    'SELECT * FROM [@node].[database_name].dbo.table_name'
);

DECLARE @paramList NVARCHAR(400) =
(
    '@node int'
)

exec sp_executesql @sqlCommand, @paramlist, @node;
```

So this is the simple query I'm attempting to run. 9044 is fine. Running that query normally works perfectly (obviously I've removed the db and table names). Not entirely sure what is wrong with it.  The error I get is:

> Msg 7202, Level 11, State 2, Line 1
>   Could not find server '@node' in sys.servers. Verify that the correct server name was specified. If necessary, execute the stored procedure sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sys.servers.

Any ideas on how to fix this issue or should I just write the query and use `EXEC (@sql)`

Comment: Are you saying your dynamic SQL is failing, but executing static SQL is working? Against the same server/database AND from the same server/database? Executing sp_addlinkedserver '9044' on the database/server where you are executing should fix the issue.

Comment: is @Node refering to a linked server named 9044?

Comment: What happens if you convert @node to an nvarchar?

Comment: Yeah fixed by converting @node to nvarchar had just using the last part (exec(@sql))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my thinking and test it only allow parameter in query part like in where and other condition.

Try this way.

```
declare @node int = 9044;

DECLARE @sqlCommand NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
(
    'SELECT * FROM [@node].[database_name].dbo.table_name'
);

DECLARE @paramList NVARCHAR(400) =
(
    '@node int'
)


SET @sqlCommand  = REPLACE(@sqlCommand , '@node',@node)
exec sp_executesql @sqlCommand, @paramlist, @node;
```

Comment: I'll definitely try this out.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are using 3-dot notation which defines the `server.db.table` @nodes is looking for a server of this name ...are you looking for this server name dynamically.. the best way would be to create a linked server object or alias and refer to it this was i.e

```
MyServer = dev-sql-server.AdventureWorks etc
```

Or you may just need to get rid of the extra [@node].

Comment: Yeah, @node will be determined by a loop.